# length of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^{50}+x+1)\mathbb{C}[x]$ as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, irreducible-polynomials, quotient-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was wondering how to compute the length of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^{50}+x+1)\mathbb{C}[x]$ as an $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module or how to proceed in general when you have such a large quotient, as you can´t just wirte down a decompositionseries. I know that the maximal Ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are of the form $(x-a)$ with $a\in\mathbb{C}$, but im a bit confused how to compute the length now.

Comment: You should know how $x^{50}+x+1$ factors in $\Bbb{C}[x]$. In general terms.

Comment: I know that, so you can just always add the factor $(x-\zeta_i)$ in the ideal and get a decomposition series of length 100 right?

Comment: Why $100$? Are there $100$ such factors?

Comment: oh nevermind, I somehow though about $x^{100}+x+1$, I meant 50